# Redux store access from components

Tags: react-redux

I have a react app using redux.  I am using connect to mapStatetoProps and mapDispatchtoProps.  Everything works and I'm able to call actions and pass them to my reducer which then sets up the state.  I can then access the state using props because my application is wrapped around react's Provider.

My questions are conceptual.

1. can I have the store be automatically populated when my application starts so that a call to props accesses the data initially loaded?
2. why does an action trigger all reducer functions? shouldn't it only trigger the reducer corresponding to the called action?
3. if a particular reducer is called, shouldn't the state changes it makes then be available to all components via props?

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally you specify the initial state within your reducer, like so

```js
function reducer(state = initialState, action) { ... }
```

If your initial state is loaded asynchronously, then you'd additionally want something else, maybe throw in a spinner or defer creating store and rendering app.

2. You can only have a subscription to the whole store, and not to individual parts of the state. There is no mapping between the actions and reducers. There's benefits to that as well as disadvantages. The benefit is that you only have 1 subscription point, which drastically increases simplicity. `connect` will automatically deal with whether a component needs to rerender and update based on the current and previous props. The disadvantage is that the speed is not as good, I've even done some benchmarks in the past, but the it is still acceptable.
3. The components will only update if their mapStateToProps parts of the state changed. This reduces unnecessary updates, so, always provide those parts of the state in mapStateToProps if the component depends on them.

Comment: For 1:  I have the initial state defaulted to an empty object.  The idea is to have it populated from an action call in the component.  The problem is that I call the action in my componentWillMount.  After the call, I'm not sure how to access the new state created by the action call by calling props from within componentWillMount. I've tried accessing the state in componentDidMountn, but by then it is too late.  I've also tried accessing it in componentWillReceiveProps, but that does not get called initially.  I think I'm having trouble with the react/redux lifecycle.

Comment: You should be able to get hold the new state in [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)